# HttpClientFactory HttpClient Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: asp.net, web, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I am implementing a service for posting data to an external RestAPI.

What I did as below:

1. Service definition:

   ```cs
   public class ExternalOutputService : IExternalOutputService
   {
       private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

       public ExternalOutputService(HttpClient httpClient)
       {
           _httpClient = httpClient;
       }

       public async Task<object> Send(object data, string baseAddress, string uri)
       {
           try
           {
               HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data);
               response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

           }
           catch (Exception ex) {
               Console.Write(ex.Message);
           }

           return response.Content;
       }  
   }
   ```
2. Add `services.AddHttpClient<IExternalOutputService, ExternalOutputService>();` in Startup
3. Use the injected the service and call the Send method.

```
public class ConfigurableOutput
{
    private readonly IExternalOutputService _externalOutputService;
    public ConfigurableOutput(IExternalOutputService externalOutputService) 
    {
        _externalOutputService = externalOutputService;
    }
    public override async Task<object> Run(object input)
    {
       await _externalOutputService.Send(input.data, "URI address");
    }
 }
```

But when I run it and hit the httpclient send line, it would throw an exception with 'Cannot access a disposed object'

Anyone has idea or advice?

Hi guys, I finally find the issue.

In another DI extension class, the class has already been registered.

```
context.Services.AddTransient<IExternalOutputService, ExternalOutputService>();
```

So removed this line and only keeps

```
 services.AddHttpClient<IExternalOutputService, ExternalOutputService>();
```

It is all good now.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `IExternalOutputService` implementation and checked at which line the error occures? Maybe at the return statement?

Comment: Yes. I have done that.
 HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data);
This line is throwing the exception.

Comment: And besides that, I also tried that directly adding a httpclient in that same block and it works fine. That means the DI httpclient which comes out of the httpclientfactory was the issue. I am still investigating why is the httpclient from httpclientfactory has been disposed before using it. I am not sure if I use the httpclientfactory correctly. But based on the article and docs I touched, it should be no more tricks I think. Em........

Comment: Ok, one more idea: is this a named or a typed client? In other words: how do you register this client?

Comment: This is a typed client. I registered this class in startup.
services.AddHttpClient<IExternalOutputService, ExternalOutputService>();
        services.AddCmsAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddCms()
            .AddAdminUserRegistration()
            .AddEmbeddedLocalization<Startup>();

Comment: ah ,missed that bit in your question. sorry.

Comment: Have you tried using `IHttpclientFactory` and then _factory.CreateClient() to create a client?

Comment: Tried that, that is fine. Both creation from httpclientFactory or new httpclient are working okay.

Comment: how is this "ConfigurableOutput" is added to services. scoped or transient? is it implementing any interface ?

Comment: Please post a minimal repro.

Comment: Are you sure the HttpClient is the disposed object? Could be the object passed as parameter?

Comment: @Alpha75 yes, I am pretty sure it is the httpClient. The params are fine.